# Why does my bash script hang?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a bash script that will check +1000 domains if they are expired. I use a a for loop to iterate over all users in `/var/cpanel/users/*`. It works great for like the 10 first users (loops) then it just hangs.

A weird thing is that I can stop the script with `Ctrl+Z` and then start the script again with `fg` and it continues to work normal for about +10 users but then it hangs again.

This is my scirpt:

```
# File that will have the result.
file="domain-result.txt"

printf "USER\t\tDOMAIN\t\t\tREPORT\n" > "$file"
printf "\n" >> "$file"

# For loop to iterate over all users in cpanel.
for z in /var/cpanel/users/*;
do
     # Only files can be used.
     if [[ -f "$z" ]]
     then

     # Get the domain name.
     awk -F'=' '/DNS=/ {print $2}' "$z" | while read row;
     do
            # If there's no domain name than skip to next account.
            if [[ -z "$row" ]]; then continue; fi

            printf "Checking domain: %s...done\n" "$row"

            # Execute whois command on the domain. 
            whois=$( /usr/bin/whois $row | grep 'not found' )

            # Get the username.
            user=$( echo "$z" | awk -F'/' '{print $5}' )

            if [[ -n "$whois" ]]
            then
                    printf "%s\t\t%s\t\t%s - EXPIRED\n" "$user" "$row" "$whois" >> "$file"
                    break
             else
                    continue
             fi
      done

      else
            continue
      fi
done

printf "\n"
printf "Total: $( sed '1,2d' "$file" | wc -l ) expired domains.\n"
```

This is a sample of how the files in `/var/cpanel/users/*` look like:

```
DNS=stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: You should add `#!/bin/bash -x` and try to get further information on where it exactly is stuck.

Comment: @BarisDemiray I have done `set -x` but there's nothing helpful. Everything seems just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you were being slapped down for WHOIS abuse.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Perhaps, but the weird thing is that the script always stops on the same domain. And when I do a `whois` on the domain that it stopped on, it works just fine and gives me a report.

Comment: I don't see how that contradicts me. Once you slow down, it works again.

Comment: Thank you @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams! You were right about the whois abuse...I added a sleep on 2 seconds and now it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for pointing out WHOIS abuse. I got it to work by adding a `sleep 2` to the `for loop`. Now it works great.